# Having two <legend> in a fieldset

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to have two legends inside a fieldset. The first one is an image on the center of the fieldset and the other one should be another image on the very right side of the fieldset. Below is my code, the first legend works perfectly fine, but I do not know how to make a second one as shown on the picture below.

```
<fieldset style="width: 500px;">
    <legend style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
      <img style="height: 200px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/3RyXECr.jpg">
    </legend>

    <legend style="display: block;">
      <img style="height: 20px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/dOhyP62.png">
    </legend>

</fieldset>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, you're only allowed one...just position the image absolutely in relation to the parent **without wrapping it in a `legend`**

```css
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:100px; /* half height of legend image */
  transform:translate(50%, -50%);
  background:white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="width: 400px;">
    <legend style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
      <img style="height: 200px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/3RyXECr.jpg">
    </legend>
      <img style="height: 20px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/dOhyP62.png" class="close">

</fieldset>
```